# How to use Primary Key in Django context view to render on html in python for loop

Tags: python, html, django, render, primary-key

I have this method in my views followed by my html:

```py
def index(request):

    context = {
        "user": User.objects.get(id = request.session['user_id']),
        "book": Book.objects.all(),
        "review": Book.objects.get(pk=1).book_reviews.all()
    }
    return render(request, "books_home.html", context)
```

```html
    {% for Book in book %}
            {{Book.contributor.id}}<br>
            Book Title: <a href="{{Book.id}}">{{Book.title}}</a><br>
            Author: {{Book.author.name}}<br>
            Contributor: <a href="{{Book.contributor.id}}">{{Book.contributor.first_name}} {{Book.contributor.last_name}}</a><br>
            {% for book_reviews in review %}
                <a href="{{User.id}}">{{book_reviews.poster.first_name}} {{book_reviews.poster.last_name}}</a> says: {{book_reviews.content}}<br>
                Rating: {{book_reviews.rating}}<br>
                Posted on: {{book_reviews.created_at}}<br>
            {% endfor %}
            {% if Book.contributor.id == request.session.user_id %} <a href="reads/{{Book.id}}/delete">Delete All</a>{% endif %}
            <hr>
```

I'm having a problem with "review": `Book.objects.get(pk=1).book_reviews.all()`, the `pk=1` is the problem. I don't know how to run through each pk so that each review is rendered, not just those with `pk=1`.

models

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    contributor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "book_added", 
    on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name = "book_written", 
    on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class Review(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_reviews", 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name="book_reviews", 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

Comment: Include the model(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviews are related to books, so you don't need to add reviews the context separately. The reviews will come from the book during iteration in the template. Ideally you'd also use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) in the view to make the database query more efficient.

Depending on your model setup, what you'd do is something like;

```py
def index(request):

    context = {
        "user": User.objects.get(id = request.session['user_id']),
        "books": Book.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_reviews'),
    }
    return render(request, "books_home.html", context)
```

This would work if your model linked to reviews like this with the related name;

```py
class Book(models.Model):

    reviews = models.ManyToManyField(Review, related_name='book_reviews')
```

Then your template would do something like

```html
{% for book in books %}
    {{ book.title }}
    {% for review in book.reviews.all %}
        {{ review }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

There's an article on this here; https://medium.com/codeptivesolutions/prefetch-related-and-select-related-in-django-90f07a2379c0

Code from comment;

```sh
>>> books = Book.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_reviews')
>>> for books in Book.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_reviews'): 
>>>     print(books.book_reviews) 
>>> reads_app.Review.None reads_app.Review.None
```

So I think what you want to do with this example is;

```sh
>>> books = Book.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_reviews')
>>> for book in books: 
>>>     print(book.book_reviews.all())
```

That should print the `Review` queryset. `book.book_reviews` should be the `RelatedManager` so you should be able to query that with `all()`, `filter()` etc

Comment: hmmm, sorry it's just not working. does it have to be a ManyToMany relationship to work?
I updated the post with my models.

Comment: @TheBongo No you don't need to use an M2M. That was just an example as you hadn't shared your models at the time. `prefetch_related` is how you efficiently get the objects on the reverse foreign key. However if it's proving problematic for you, drop that part and just do `.all()`. It'll hammer the database so shouldn't be used in production, but to get the proof of concept together, it might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help dude. I really appreciate it. 
I'm trying to run things in the shell to test it out, but I just can't seem to get things to print properly. 
in the shell:
'books = Book.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_reviews')
for books in Book.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_reviews'):
     print(books.book_reviews)
reads_app.Review.None
reads_app.Review.None'

I'm not sure what this means. 
(I'm using Django 2.2, if that's relevant). 
Again I appreciate your help, I'm very new to coding.

Comment: @TheBongo I updated my answer to try to address that code.